# how to get variable in javascript and put it to get geolocation in here map?

Tags: javascript, here-api

Can anyone solve this code? 
i have some javascript code geolocation and here map script, i want to put geolocation coordinate in here map script..
here bellow my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0.12.2/mapsjs-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0.12.2/mapsjs-core.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0.12.2/mapsjs-service.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0.12.2/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0.12.2/mapsjs-pano.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0.12.2/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="getLocation()">My Location</button><br/>
 <input type="text" id="latpos" name="latpos">
 <input type="text" id="longpos" name="longpos">
 <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />
 <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >

var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
      var origlat= position.coords.latitude ;
      var origlong= position.coords.longitude ;
      var lat=document.getElementById("latpos");
      lat.value=origlat;
      var lon=document.getElementById("longpos");
      lon.value=origlong;
}


function addMarkerAndSetViewBounds(map) {
  var latitu="-6.811408423530006";
  var longitu= "110.85068956017494";
  var origl= origlat;
  var origlo= origlong;
  var Isone = new H.map.Marker({lat:latitu, lng:longitu}),
      geol = new H.map.Marker({lat:origl, lng:origlo}),
      group = new H.map.Group();

  group.addObjects([Isone , geol]);
  map.addObject(group);

// get geo bounding box for the group and set it to the map
  map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds());

 }
    /Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
  var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
    useCIT: false,
  });
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:50, lng:5},
  zoom: 15
});

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...

addMarkerAndSetViewBounds(map);

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but, that code didn't work fine.. 
how to get value `var origlat` and `var origlong` in variable `var origl` and `var origlo`?
can anyone help me to fix this code run correctly

Comment: `x.alert`??? Why does an element have an alert method?

Comment: it is only copy n paste from  html5 geoocation code..  i'm newbie in coding.. please guide me to fix my code above..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Answer (score 0):

You should make origlat, origlong global variables, instead of local variable.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: `function showPosition(position) {
          var origlat= position.coords.latitude ;
          var origlong= position.coords.longitude ;
          var lat=document.getElementById("latpos");
          lat.value=origlat;
          var lon=document.getElementById("longpos");
          lon.value=origlong;
}
var late= document.getElementById("latpos").value ;
var longe= document.getElementById("longpos").value ;

function addMarkerAndSetViewBounds(map) {
  var origl= late;
  var origlo= longe;
  var geol = new H.map.Marker({lat:origl, lng:origlo}),` but no value in var geol, can you help me?